# WPF - C# - Print a XAML Datagrid - multiplie Pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, printing, datagrid

XAML - Code:

```
<Grid Name="Label">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Text" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Label Content="Text" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Label Content="Text" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Label Content="Text" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
```

Now I want to print this Label. When I use the Function "PrintVisual" in a Loop the Printer stops after each Label for 1 - 2 seconds.

Therefore I tested this Code example but it doesen't work.

```
FixedDocument doc = new FixedDocument();

                PageContent pc = new PageContent();
                doc.Pages.Add(pc);
                FixedPage page = new FixedPage();
                pc.Child = page;


                for (int i = 1; i <= int.Parse(tbCount.Text); i++)
                {
                    page.Children.Add((UIElement)Label);
                }

                printDialog.PrintDocument(doc.DocumentPaginator, "Labels");
```

The error is thrown when the Label will be added to the page.